# BeautifulSoup not getting all HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using Python 2.7, Beautiful Soup 3, Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015. I was trying to get phone numbers off websites like [this one](https://www.ahd.com/free_profile/450369/Childress_Regional_Medical_Center/Childress/Texas/), but Beautiful Soup does not get all of the HTML. I can't seem to find a pattern in what gets saved and what doesn't. This is the code I use to get the data. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


hospital = requests.get('https://www.ahd.com/free_profile/450369/Childress_Regional_Medical_Center/Childress/Texas/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(hospital.text)
text = soup.getText()
```

Comment: check `hospital.status_code` and what is inside `hospital.text`

Comment: I actually took a look at the output of text and there doesn't seem to be any missing output. All of the data in the page is present. What parts of the page were missing before?

Comment: It's missing the table with the phone number in it, that's the big one. Just seems to be randomly skipping around the code.

Status code = 200

Comment: I can't post hospital.text, it's too long

Comment: This question seems similar to one I saw in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913316/beautiful-soup-doesnt-get-full-webpage/ The solution that worked then was to try and parse the page with a different parser (BeautifulSoup supports a bunch of them). Try using `lxml` or `html5lib`.

Comment: How do I do that in BS3? The constructor is different, I believe

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. There was a small typo in the website address. Now  just have to figure out why my regex isn't working.

Comment: @Sig but why are you using BeautifulSoup 3 in the first place? It's very old and is not maintained anymore

Comment: Long story, it was a really bad idea to fix another problem I was having.